# OpenCV image alignment how to rotate after homography

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm a novice at openCV, currently i'm following [this](https://learnopencv.com/image-alignment-feature-based-using-opencv-c-python/) tutorial on image alignment, i have the following image and template for testing
scanned image(test_image.jpg):
[image]

template image(template.jpg):
[image]

and the following python code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import cv2
import numpy as np

MAX_FEATURES = 500
GOOD_MATCH_PERCENT = 0.15


def alignImages(im1, im2):

    # Convert images to grayscale
    im1Gray = cv2.cvtColor(im1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    im2Gray = cv2.cvtColor(im2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Detect ORB features and compute descriptors.
    orb = cv2.ORB_create(MAX_FEATURES)
    keypoints1, descriptors1 = orb.detectAndCompute(im1Gray, None)
    keypoints2, descriptors2 = orb.detectAndCompute(im2Gray, None)

    # Match features.
    matcher = cv2.DescriptorMatcher_create(
        cv2.DESCRIPTOR_MATCHER_BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING)
    matches = list(matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2, None))

    # Sort matches by score
    matches.sort(key=lambda x: x.distance, reverse=False)

    # Remove not so good matches
    numGoodMatches = int(len(matches) * GOOD_MATCH_PERCENT)
    matches = matches[:numGoodMatches]

    # Draw top matches
    imMatches = cv2.drawMatches(im1, keypoints1, im2, keypoints2, matches, None)
    cv2.imwrite("matches.jpg", imMatches)

    # Extract location of good matches
    points1 = np.zeros((len(matches), 2), dtype=np.float32)
    points2 = np.zeros((len(matches), 2), dtype=np.float32)

    for i, match in enumerate(matches):
        points1[i, :] = keypoints1[match.queryIdx].pt
        points2[i, :] = keypoints2[match.trainIdx].pt

    # Find homography
    h, mask = cv2.findHomography(points1, points2, cv2.RANSAC)

    # Use homography
    height, width, channels = im2.shape
    im1Reg = cv2.warpPerspective(im1, h, (width, height))

    return im1Reg, h


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Read reference image
    refFilename = "template.jpg"
    print("Reading reference image : ", refFilename)
    imReference = cv2.imread(refFilename, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

    # Read image to be aligned
    imFilename = "test_image.jpg"
    print("Reading image to align : ", imFilename)
    im = cv2.imread(imFilename, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

    print("Aligning images ...")
    # Registered image will be resotred in imReg.
    # The estimated homography will be stored in h.
    imReg, h = alignImages(im, imReference)

    # Write aligned image to disk.
    outFilename = "aligned.jpg"
    print("Saving aligned image : ", outFilename)
    cv2.imwrite(outFilename, imReg)

    # Print estimated homography
    print("Estimated homography : \n",  h)
```

I get the following results after i ran the script:

matches.jpg:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

I was able to get the image when i increase the amount of orb features to 2000

aligned.jpg
[image]

But the homography is still not rotating the image, how can i rotate the image to the same position as the template?

Comment: you are following bad tutorials. discard anything that doesn't include Lowe's ratio test. discard anything that uses bad descriptors (ORB) or silly algorithms (bruteforce). you want sift or akaze, and you want flann.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz got it, i will try to read up on those algorithms, it's surprising that the article can have such good result from ORB descriptors if it's that bad

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz i was able to the the match form shape from the scanned image by increasing max features to 2000, but the warpPerspective was not able to rotate to the same position as the template. Do you know why it doesn't apply?

Comment: [Four Point Perspective Transform](https://pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/25/4-point-opencv-getperspective-transform-example/)

Answer (score 4):

There are two types of forms to finding a homography (forward and backward), but if you already found the homography, applying it can be done without using `opencv` as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
# creating the homogenious coordinates
src_h, src_w, _ = src_image.shape
values = np.matrix.reshape(src_image, (-1, 3), order='F')
yy, xx = np.meshgrid(np.arange(src_h), np.arange(src_w))
input_flat = np.concatenate((xx.reshape((1, -1)), yy.reshape((1, -1)), np.ones_like(xx.reshape((1, -1)))), axis=0)
# applying the homography and converting back to homogenious coordinates
points = np.matmul(homography, input_flat)
points_homogeneous = points[0:2, :] / points[2, :]
# interpolating the result to nicely fit the grid coordinates
dst_image_shape = [400, 400] # could be any number here
yy, xx = np.meshgrid(np.arange(dst_image_shape[1]), np.arange(dst_image_shape[0]))
src_image_warp = griddata(np.transpose(points_homogeneous ), values_relevant, (yy, xx), method='linear')
#numerical rounding
src_image_warp[np.isnan(src_image_warp)] = 0
src_image_warp[src_image_warp > 255] = 255
src_image_warp = np.uint8(src_image_warp)
```

Note that this is done for a 1 channel image, for RGB image this has to be done for each channel searately. In addition, this could be made to run faster by interpolating only the relevant coordinates since the interpolation is the most time-consuming operation.

With `opencv` this can be done by:

```
import cv2
image_dst = cv2.warpPerspective(image_src, homography, size)  # size is a tuple (width, height) of the destination image
```

Read more on homographies and the opencv implementation [here](https://learnopencv.com/homography-examples-using-opencv-python-c/).

### Finding the homography

The homography can be found without using `opencv` but that requires knowlage in linear algebra adn the explanation is a bit lengthy, if needed I will post it as an edit. For any practical case however, the homography can be found using `opencv` as follows:

```
homography, status = cv2.findHomography(pts_src, pts_dst)
```

where `pts_src` are coordinates in the original image and `pts_dst` are their matching location in the destination image. Since you already found the point pairs, this will yield you the homography (`opencv` optimizes the hmography for minimal distortion in the backward operation which is the correct way to perform homography computations).

Answer (score 2):

You have a homography `h` calculated from `findHomography` and you can use `warpPerspective` to transform the template to have the same perspective as the photo.

Now you just need to **invert** the homography, and apply it to the *photo* instead of the *template*.

Either use `np.linalg.inv` for that, or pass the `WARP_INVERSE_MAP` flag to `warpPerspetive` instead.

[image]